# Is it possible to enable SSL on the MSOpenTech Redis distribution

Tags: redis

I am trying to host the [MSOpenTech Redis](https://github.com/MSOpenTech/Redis) instance securely.  Looking at the base [Redis Documentation](http://redis.io/topics/security) I see a reference to using an [SSL proxy](http://www.tarsnap.com/spiped.html) on a linux box.  Is there a windows equivalent or is the intended usage pattern to limit access via network constraints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this using [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html) to perform the SSL offloading.  I had to convert my server pfx to a pem using openssl and place it in the `conf` directory of the stunnel install.  To keep it clean I move the port redis is listening on to 6380 so the connection topology is client ---(TLS 1.2) --> server:6379 --> Localhost:6380.

**StackExchange.Redis Client Initialization**

```
ConfigurationOptions options = new ConfigurationOptions
{
    options.Ssl = true;
    Password = "foobared"
};
options.EndPoints.Add("localhost:6379");
```

**Stunnel Configuration**

```
[redis-proxy]
sslVersion = all
options = NO_SSLv2
options = NO_SSLv3
cert = stunnel.pem
accept = 6379
connect  = 6380
```

**Openssl Command**

`openssl pkcs12 -in myservercert.pfx -out stunnel.pem -nodes`